# Golang checks for equilateral, isosceles, or scalene triangle

Tags: programming-challenge, go

For me, learning the basics of a new programming language is best done through some easy to intermediate challenges. Here's one that's rather well known and relatively simple - determine if a triangle is equilateral, isosceles, or scalene.

Here's my try in Golang. Since I'm totally new to Go, I'm pretty sure this can be improved. How can I get this code to be more, well, Go-like? On the bottom, there's a test suit (was not written by me thou).

```
// package triangle contains methods for determining if a triangle is equilateral, isosceles, or scalene
package triangle

import (
    "sort"
    "math"
)

type Kind int

const (
    NaT = 1 // not a triangle
    Equ = 2 // equilateral
    Iso = 3 // isosceles
    Sca = 4 // scalene
)

// KindForomSides checks if a triangle is equilateral, isosceles, or scalene
func KindFromSides(a, b, c float64) Kind {
    var k Kind

    if !IsTriangle(a, b, c) {
        k = NaT
        return k
    } else if a == b && a == c {
        k = Equ
        return k
    } else if a == b || a == c || b == c {
        k = Iso
        return k
    } else {
        k = Sca
        return k
    }
}

// IsTriangle checks for triangle inequality
func IsTriangle(a, b, c float64) bool {
    var sides []float64
    sides = append(sides, a, b, c)
    sort.Float64s(sides)
    sides[0], sides[1], sides[2] = a, b, c
    // Check if side values are not NaN or Infinity
    for _, value := range sides {
        if math.IsNaN(value) || math.IsInf(value, 0) {
            return false
        }
    }
    // Check if sides are not negative values
    if !(a > float64(0) && b > float64(0) && c > float64(0)) {
        return false
    }

    if a + b < c || b + c < a || c + a < b {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

The test suit.

```
package triangle

import (
    "math"
    "testing"
)

type testCase struct {
    want    Kind
    a, b, c float64
}

// basic test cases
var testData = []testCase{
    {Equ, 2, 2, 2},    // same length
    {Equ, 10, 10, 10}, // a little bigger
    {Iso, 3, 4, 4},    // last two sides equal
    {Iso, 4, 3, 4},    // first and last sides equal
    {Iso, 4, 4, 3},    // first two sides equal
    {Iso, 10, 10, 2},  // again
    {Iso, 2, 4, 2},    // a "triangle" that is just a line is still OK
    {Sca, 3, 4, 5},    // no sides equal
    {Sca, 10, 11, 12}, // again
    {Sca, 5, 4, 2},    // descending order
    {Sca, .4, .6, .3}, // small sides
    {Sca, 1, 4, 3},    // a "triangle" that is just a line is still OK
    {Sca, 5, 4, 6},    // 2a == b+c looks like equilateral, but isn't always.
    {Sca, 6, 4, 5},    // 2a == b+c looks like equilateral, but isn't always.
    {NaT, 0, 0, 0},    // zero length
    {NaT, 3, 4, -5},   // negative length
    {NaT, 1, 1, 3},    // fails triangle inequality
    {NaT, 2, 5, 2},    // another
    {NaT, 7, 3, 2},    // another
}

// generate cases with NaN and Infs, append to basic cases
func init() {
    nan := math.NaN()
    pinf := math.Inf(1)
    ninf := math.Inf(-1)
    nf := make([]testCase, 4*4*4)
    i := 0
    for _, a := range []float64{3, nan, pinf, ninf} {
        for _, b := range []float64{4, nan, pinf, ninf} {
            for _, c := range []float64{5, nan, pinf, ninf} {
                nf[i] = testCase{NaT, a, b, c}
                i++
            }
        }
    }
    testData = append(testData, nf[1:]...)
}

// Test that the kinds are not equal to each other.
// If they are equal, then TestKind will return false positives.
func TestKindsNotEqual(t *testing.T) {
    kindsAndNames := []struct {
        kind Kind
        name string
    }{
        {Equ, "Equ"},
        {Iso, "Iso"},
        {Sca, "Sca"},
        {NaT, "NaT"},
    }

    for i, pair1 := range kindsAndNames {
        for j := i + 1; j < len(kindsAndNames); j++ {
            pair2 := kindsAndNames[j]
            if pair1.kind == pair2.kind {
                t.Fatalf("%s should not be equal to %s", pair1.name, pair2.name)
            }
        }
    }
}

func TestKind(t *testing.T) {
    for _, test := range testData {
        got := KindFromSides(test.a, test.b, test.c)
        if got != test.want {
            t.Fatalf("Triangle with sides, %g, %g, %g = %v, want %v",
                test.a, test.b, test.c, got, test.want)
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkKind(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        for _, test := range testData {
            KindFromSides(test.a, test.b, test.c)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

few things to say,

the `Kind` constants can be declared using the `iota` keyword.

```golang
// Triangle kinds
const (
    NaT = iota // not a triangle
    Equ        // equilateral
    Iso        // isosceles
    Sca        // scalene
)
```

Some comments are broken btw, the linters will complain. Do you use one ?
Using atom and the go-plus plugin, it lints out of the box. Something similar must exists for vscode, for example.

Also, the naming `triangle.IsTriangle` does look repetitive, it is preferably avoided.

The `KindFromSides` function can declare the return variable in the out signature parameter and set its default value to the default original else case. It is somewhat less complex, so somewhat preferred.

```golang
// KindFromSides checks if a triangle is equilateral, isosceles, or scalene
func KindFromSides(a,b,c float64) (k Kind) {
    k = Sca

    if !IsTriangle(a,b,c) {
        k = NaT
    } else if a == b && a == c {
        k = Equ
    } else if a == b || a == c || b == c {
        k = Iso
    }
    return k
}
```

You can also re arrange the constants declaration so `Sca` is the zero value

```golang
// Triangle kinds
const (
    Sca = iota // scalene
    NaT        // not a triangle
    Equ        // equilateral
    Iso        // isosceles
)

// KindFromSides checks if a triangle is equilateral, isosceles, or scalene
func KindFromSides(sides []float64) (k Kind) {
    a := sides[0]
    b := sides[1]
    c := sides[2]

    if !IsTriangle(sides) {
        k = NaT
    } else if a == b && a == c {
        k = Equ
    } else if a == b || a == c || b == c {
        k = Iso
    }
    return k
}
```

Although, imho, it is better written like this

```golang
// Triangle kinds
const (
    NaT = iota // not a triangle
    Equ        // equilateral
    Iso        // isosceles
    Sca        // scalene
)

// KindFromSides checks if a triangle is equilateral, isosceles, or scalene
func KindFromSides(sides []float64) (k Kind) {
    a := sides[0]
    b := sides[1]
    c := sides[2]

    if IsTriangle(sides) {
        k = Sca
        if a == b && a == c {
            k = Equ
        } else if a == b || a == c || b == c {
            k = Iso
        }
    }
    return k
}
```

The tests are OK, although you don't use any un-exported `triangle` symbol, so it should belong to the `triangle_test` package.

Now i ran the benchmark,

```sh
$ go test -bench=. -benchmem
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: test/triangle
BenchmarkKind-4       200000         11551 ns/op        5248 B/op        164 allocs/op
PASS
ok      test/triangle   2.432s
```

That is a lot of allocations for such thing.

I re run the benchmark, enabling the memory profiler,

```sh
$ go test -bench=. -benchmem -memprofile=mem.out
```

Then open it

```sh
$ go tool pprof mem.out 
File: triangle.test
Type: alloc_space
Time: Dec 15, 2019 at 8:16pm (CET)
Entering interactive mode (type "help" for commands, "o" for options)
(pprof) top
Showing nodes accounting for 539.52MB, 100% of 539.52MB total
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
  273.51MB 50.70% 50.70%   273.51MB 50.70%  sort.Float64s
  266.01MB 49.30%   100%   539.52MB   100%  test/triangle.IsTriangle
         0     0%   100%   539.52MB   100%  test/triangle.BenchmarkKind
         0     0%   100%   539.52MB   100%  test/triangle.KindFromSides
         0     0%   100%   539.52MB   100%  testing.(*B).launch
         0     0%   100%   539.52MB   100%  testing.(*B).runN
(pprof) list Float
Total: 539.52MB
ROUTINE ======================== sort.Float64s in /home/mh-cbon/.gvm/gos/go1.12.7/src/sort/sort.go
  273.51MB   273.51MB (flat, cum) 50.70% of Total
         .          .    306:// Ints sorts a slice of ints in increasing order.
         .          .    307:func Ints(a []int) { Sort(IntSlice(a)) }
         .          .    308:
         .          .    309:// Float64s sorts a slice of float64s in increasing order
         .          .    310:// (not-a-number values are treated as less than other values).
  273.51MB   273.51MB    311:func Float64s(a []float64) { Sort(Float64Slice(a)) }
         .          .    312:
         .          .    313:// Strings sorts a slice of strings in increasing order.
         .          .    314:func Strings(a []string) { Sort(StringSlice(a)) }
         .          .    315:
         .          .    316:// IntsAreSorted tests whether a slice of ints is sorted in increasing order.
(pprof) list IsTriangle
Total: 539.52MB
ROUTINE ======================== test/triangle.IsTriangle in /home/mh-cbon/gow/src/test/triangle/main.go
  266.01MB   539.52MB (flat, cum)   100% of Total
         .          .     35:}
         .          .     36:
         .          .     37:// IsTriangle checks for triangle inequality
         .          .     38:func IsTriangle(a, b, c float64) bool {
         .          .     39:   var sides []float64
  266.01MB   266.01MB     40:   sides = append(sides, a, b, c)
         .   273.51MB     41:   sort.Float64s(sides)
         .          .     42:   sides[0], sides[1], sides[2] = a, b, c
         .          .     43:   // Check if side values are not NaN or Infinity
         .          .     44:   for _, value := range sides {
         .          .     45:       if math.IsNaN(value) || math.IsInf(value, 0) {
         .          .     46:           return false
(pprof) exit
```

It shows this algorithm allocates twice, within `triangle.IsTriangle`, then within `sort.Float64s`.

Unfortunately, sort.Float64s allocation is not avoidable, unless you receive a sort.Float64 slice directly, but that might sound a bit awkward for the api signature.

In below proposal the allocation within IsTriangle function is removed by receiving directly a slice of float64s. To improve more the allocation and prevent false positive the tests are also updated.

**main.go**

```golang
// package triangle contains methods for determining if a triangle is equilateral, isosceles, or scalene
package triangle

import (
    "math"
    "sort"
)

// Kind of triangle
type Kind int

// Triangle kinds
const (
    NaT = iota // not a triangle
    Equ        // equilateral
    Iso        // isosceles
    Sca        // scalene
)

// KindFromSides checks if a triangle is equilateral, isosceles, or scalene
func KindFromSides(sides []float64) (k Kind) {
    k = Sca

    a := sides[0]
    b := sides[1]
    c := sides[2]

    if !IsTriangle(sides) {
        k = NaT
    } else if a == b && a == c {
        k = Equ
    } else if a == b || a == c || b == c {
        k = Iso
    }
    return k
}

// IsTriangle checks for triangle inequality
func IsTriangle(sides []float64) bool {
    // sides := []float64{a, b, c}

    // Check if side values are not NaN or Infinity
    for _, value := range sides {
        if math.IsNaN(value) || math.IsInf(value, 0) {
            return false
        }
    }
    sort.Float64s(sides)

    // sides[0], sides[1], sides[2] = a, b, c
    a, b, c := sides[0], sides[1], sides[2] // instead ?

    // Check if sides are not negative values
    if !(a > float64(0) && b > float64(0) && c > float64(0)) {
        return false
    }

    if a+b < c || b+c < a || c+a < b {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

**main_test.go**

```golang
package triangle

import (
    "math"
    "testing"
)

type testCase struct {
    want    Kind
    a, b, c float64
}

// basic test cases
var testData = []testCase{
    {Equ, 2, 2, 2},    // same length
    {Equ, 10, 10, 10}, // a little bigger
    {Iso, 3, 4, 4},    // last two sides equal
    {Iso, 4, 3, 4},    // first and last sides equal
    {Iso, 4, 4, 3},    // first two sides equal
    {Iso, 10, 10, 2},  // again
    {Iso, 2, 4, 2},    // a "triangle" that is just a line is still OK
    {Sca, 3, 4, 5},    // no sides equal
    {Sca, 10, 11, 12}, // again
    {Sca, 5, 4, 2},    // descending order
    {Sca, .4, .6, .3}, // small sides
    {Sca, 1, 4, 3},    // a "triangle" that is just a line is still OK
    {Sca, 5, 4, 6},    // 2a == b+c looks like equilateral, but isn't always.
    {Sca, 6, 4, 5},    // 2a == b+c looks like equilateral, but isn't always.
    {NaT, 0, 0, 0},    // zero length
    {NaT, 3, 4, -5},   // negative length
    {NaT, 1, 1, 3},    // fails triangle inequality
    {NaT, 2, 5, 2},    // another
    {NaT, 7, 3, 2},    // another
}

// generate cases with NaN and Infs, append to basic cases
func init() {
    nan := math.NaN()
    pinf := math.Inf(1)
    ninf := math.Inf(-1)
    nf := make([]testCase, 4*4*4)
    i := 0
    for _, a := range []float64{3, nan, pinf, ninf} {
        for _, b := range []float64{4, nan, pinf, ninf} {
            for _, c := range []float64{5, nan, pinf, ninf} {
                nf[i] = testCase{NaT, a, b, c}
                i++
            }
        }
    }
    testData = append(testData, nf[1:]...)
}

// Test that the kinds are not equal to each other.
// If they are equal, then TestKind will return false positives.
func TestKindsNotEqual(t *testing.T) {
    kindsAndNames := []struct {
        kind Kind
        name string
    }{
        {Equ, "Equ"},
        {Iso, "Iso"},
        {Sca, "Sca"},
        {NaT, "NaT"},
    }

    for i, pair1 := range kindsAndNames {
        for j := i + 1; j < len(kindsAndNames); j++ {
            pair2 := kindsAndNames[j]
            if pair1.kind == pair2.kind {
                t.Fatalf("%s should not be equal to %s", pair1.name, pair2.name)
            }
        }
    }
}

func TestKind(t *testing.T) {
    sides := make([]float64, 3)
    for _, test := range testData {
        sides[0] = test.a
        sides[1] = test.b
        sides[2] = test.c
        got := KindFromSides(sides)
        if got != test.want {
            t.Fatalf("Triangle with sides, %g, %g, %g = %v, want %v",
                test.a, test.b, test.c, got, test.want)
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkKind(b *testing.B) {
    sides := make([]float64, 3)
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        for _, test := range testData {
            sides[0] = test.a
            sides[1] = test.b
            sides[2] = test.c
            KindFromSides(sides)
        }
    }
}
```

Benchmark is now

```sh
$ go test -bench=. -benchmem -memprofile=mem.out
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: test/triangle
BenchmarkKind-4       500000          2728 ns/op         608 B/op         19 allocs/op
PASS
ok      test/triangle   1.397s
$ go tool pprof mem.out 
File: triangle.test
Type: alloc_space
Time: Dec 15, 2019 at 8:20pm (CET)
Entering interactive mode (type "help" for commands, "o" for options)
(pprof) top
Showing nodes accounting for 301.01MB, 99.83% of 301.51MB total
Dropped 13 nodes (cum <= 1.51MB)
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
  301.01MB 99.83% 99.83%   301.01MB 99.83%  sort.Float64s
         0     0% 99.83%   301.01MB 99.83%  test/triangle.BenchmarkKind
         0     0% 99.83%   301.01MB 99.83%  test/triangle.IsTriangle
         0     0% 99.83%   301.01MB 99.83%  test/triangle.KindFromSides
         0     0% 99.83%   301.01MB 99.83%  testing.(*B).launch
         0     0% 99.83%   301.51MB   100%  testing.(*B).runN
(pprof) exit
```

In below version, a type `Triangle` is defined as `[]float64`, methods are attached to it, and sort.Sort* functions are replaced with specialized functions exposed by the package https://github.com/AlasdairF/Sort to reach 0 allocations.

**main.go**

```golang
// package triangle contains methods for determining if a triangle is equilateral, isosceles, or scalene
package triangle

import (
    "math"

    "github.com/AlasdairF/Sort/Float64"
)

type Triangle []float64

// Kind of triangle
type Kind int

// Triangle kinds
const (
    NaT = iota // not a triangle
    Equ        // equilateral
    Iso        // isosceles
    Sca        // scalene
)

func (sides Triangle) Kind() (k Kind) {
    a := sides[0]
    b := sides[1]
    c := sides[2]

    if sides.IsValid() {
        k = Sca
        if a == b && a == c {
            k = Equ
        } else if a == b || a == c || b == c {
            k = Iso
        }
    }
    return k
}

func (sides Triangle) IsValid() bool {
    // Check if side values are not NaN or Infinity
    for _, value := range sides {
        if math.IsNaN(value) || math.IsInf(value, 0) {
            return false
        }
    }
    sortFloat64.StableDesc(sides)

    a, b, c := sides[0], sides[1], sides[2] // instead ?

    // Check if sides are not negative values
    if !(a > float64(0) && b > float64(0) && c > float64(0)) {
        return false
    }

    if a+b < c || b+c < a || c+a < b {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

**main_test.go**

```golang
package triangle

import (
    "math"
    "testing"
)

type testCase struct {
    want    Kind
    a, b, c float64
}

// basic test cases
var testData = []testCase{
    {Equ, 2, 2, 2},    // same length
    {Equ, 10, 10, 10}, // a little bigger
    {Iso, 3, 4, 4},    // last two sides equal
    {Iso, 4, 3, 4},    // first and last sides equal
    {Iso, 4, 4, 3},    // first two sides equal
    {Iso, 10, 10, 2},  // again
    {Iso, 2, 4, 2},    // a "triangle" that is just a line is still OK
    {Sca, 3, 4, 5},    // no sides equal
    {Sca, 10, 11, 12}, // again
    {Sca, 5, 4, 2},    // descending order
    {Sca, .4, .6, .3}, // small sides
    {Sca, 1, 4, 3},    // a "triangle" that is just a line is still OK
    {Sca, 5, 4, 6},    // 2a == b+c looks like equilateral, but isn't always.
    {Sca, 6, 4, 5},    // 2a == b+c looks like equilateral, but isn't always.
    {NaT, 0, 0, 0},    // zero length
    {NaT, 3, 4, -5},   // negative length
    {NaT, 1, 1, 3},    // fails triangle inequality
    {NaT, 2, 5, 2},    // another
    {NaT, 7, 3, 2},    // another
}

// generate cases with NaN and Infs, append to basic cases
func init() {
    nan := math.NaN()
    pinf := math.Inf(1)
    ninf := math.Inf(-1)
    nf := make([]testCase, 4*4*4)
    i := 0
    for _, a := range []float64{3, nan, pinf, ninf} {
        for _, b := range []float64{4, nan, pinf, ninf} {
            for _, c := range []float64{5, nan, pinf, ninf} {
                nf[i] = testCase{NaT, a, b, c}
                i++
            }
        }
    }
    testData = append(testData, nf[1:]...)
}

// Test that the kinds are not equal to each other.
// If they are equal, then TestKind will return false positives.
func TestKindsNotEqual(t *testing.T) {
    kindsAndNames := []struct {
        kind Kind
        name string
    }{
        {Equ, "Equ"},
        {Iso, "Iso"},
        {Sca, "Sca"},
        {NaT, "NaT"},
    }

    for i, pair1 := range kindsAndNames {
        for j := i + 1; j < len(kindsAndNames); j++ {
            pair2 := kindsAndNames[j]
            if pair1.kind == pair2.kind {
                t.Fatalf("%s should not be equal to %s", pair1.name, pair2.name)
            }
        }
    }
}

func TestTriangleKind(t *testing.T) {
    tr := Triangle(make([]float64, 3))
    for _, test := range testData {
        tr[0] = test.a
        tr[1] = test.b
        tr[2] = test.c
        got := tr.Kind()
        if got != test.want {
            t.Fatalf("Triangle with sides, %g, %g, %g = %v, want %v",
                test.a, test.b, test.c, got, test.want)
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkTriangleKind(b *testing.B) {
    tr := Triangle(make([]float64, 3))
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        for _, test := range testData {
            tr[0] = test.a
            tr[1] = test.b
            tr[2] = test.c
            tr.Kind()
        }
    }
}
```

and the benchmark result,

```sh
$ go test -bench=Triangle -benchmem -memprofile=mem.out
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: test/triangle
BenchmarkTriangleKind-4       384340          2970 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
PASS
ok      test/triangle   1.181s
```

The benchmarks shows a relative slower speed, it performed `384340` iterations, with each took `2970ns`. That is because the cpu clock is reduced to prevent noise and energy consumtpion. if i am to let it go full speed, it shows:

```sh
$ go test -bench=Triangle -benchmem -memprofile=mem.out -count 4
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: test/triangle
BenchmarkTriangleKind-4      1374426           869 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkTriangleKind-4      1383519           871 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkTriangleKind-4      1376869           872 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkTriangleKind-4      1374054           873 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
PASS
ok      test/triangle   8.326s
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this comprehensive feedback!